# Using Yahoo Finance API for Minute Data?

Tags: python, api, yahoo-finance

I've found the Yahoo Finance Chart API to have minute-by-minute data for NYSE securities.

Here's an example:

http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/GOOG/chartdata;type=quote;range=1d/csv

I am trying get this data into my backtesting platform in Python. I'm not really sure how to use this API and haven't really found much documentation.

What's the best way to get the data into my program? I have considered scraping using BeautifulSoup and Mechanize but am not too sure how I would do that either.

I am hoping to backtest a strategy for at least the past 5 years.

Comment: If there's another API or way to do this without the Yahoo API, I'd love to hear suggestions too!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [API for stock price?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058323/api-for-stock-price)

Comment: For historical stock prices by API, and for APIs in general, try the ProgrammableWeb. http://www.programmableweb.com/news/96-stocks-apis-bloomberg-nasdaq-and-etrade/2013/05/22

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a library to handle the http exchange. I prefer [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

```
import requests

url='http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/GOOG/chartdata;type=quote;range=1d/csv'
response = requests.get(url)
response_body = response.content
data = response_body.split('\n')
# Timestamp, close, high, low, open, volume in data[11]
summary = data[12:17]
interval_data = data[17:]
```

You can use `interval_data_fields = interval_data.split(',')` to break apart the lines at commas, but you're better off learning off to use the python `csv` library for down the road; otherwise, what happens when some data you want comes in a CSV file that contains quoted commas?

For historical stock prices by API, and for APIs in general, try the [ProgrammableWeb](http://www.programmableweb.com/news/96-stocks-apis-bloomberg-nasdaq-and-etrade/2013/05/22).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Yahoo decided to remove their API. To handle for this, you can change the stock_price_url to the following in the code:

stock_price_url = 'https://pythonprogramming.net/yahoo_finance_replacement'

Only AAPL is supported. If you have your own source, feel free to adapt the code to suit that, or you can look into pandas for pulling data.﻿